# str_replace_all with multiple vector patterns

Tags: r, replace, stringr

I would like to replace one pattern given by a list by the other pattern given by another list.

I do it like this:

```
library(stringr)

strings$old <- c("apple banana orange", "peach apple orange", "apple orange pear", "orange apple banana", "apple orange peach")
words to replace <- c("banana", "peach", "pear")
replacements <- c("b", "p", "pe")
```

what I do:

```
current <- paste(c(replace), collapse='|')
change_to <- paste(c(replacements ), collapse='|')
strings$new <- str_replace_all(strings$old, current, change_to)
```

However, I get an error. What I would like to see is:
c("apple b orange", "p apple orange", "apple orange pe", "orange apple b", "apple orange p")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named vector in the `pattern` parameter of the `str_replace_all()` function like this:

```
strings %>% 
  mutate(new = str_replace_all(old, setNames(replacements, words_to_replace)))
```

Output:

```
                  old             new
1 apple banana orange  apple b orange
2  peach apple orange  p apple orange
3   apple orange pear apple orange pe
4 orange apple banana  orange apple b
5  apple orange peach  apple orange p
```

Input:

```
strings = data.frame(old = c("apple banana orange", "peach apple orange", "apple orange pear", "orange apple banana", "apple orange peach"))
words_to_replace <- c("banana", "peach", "pear")
replacements <- c("b", "p", "pe")
```

Comment: It works for me! Thank u for your solution, such a nerve cells saver.